# Are "conduct", "lead" and "teach" near-synonymous?

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

I am not sure if it's not idiomatic, but I rarely hear people say "conduct a course". I do often hear "lead a course", but it sounds a bit too general, and so I was wondering how correct and idiomatic the use of "lead" and "conduct" were.

For example:

> The teacher conducted a course in public administration.
>
> The teacher led a course in public administration.
>
> The teacher taught a course in public administration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, the choice of verb depends on the kind of course being taught.

If the course is a [seminar](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seminar), or another style of course where the students actively share their own ideas, "led" or "conducted" is best.  These verbs imply that the teacher does more "[moderating](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/moderator)" of discussions than traditional "teaching".

If the course is a traditional series of [lectures](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lecture) (possibly with visual examples or derivations), "taught" is best.